# Why was this NAA flag declined on a random text post?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged the first revision [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36261158/1) as NAA because it was just a random text that had nothing to do with a proper answer.

Later, this post was edited to include a proper answer, and now my NAA flag is declined, instead of disputed because the post was edited.

I flagged the post at: 2016-03-28 11:13:03Z

The post was edited in a proper answer at 2016-03-28 11:17:03Z

Comment: Edits to posts marked NAA automatically invalidate any NAA flags on that answer, as I recall. I'm not sure if that's also true for VLQ, and/or if I'm mixing up NAA with VLQ.

Comment: +1 declined flag here from that post: http://imgur.com/qEk5HkV :P

Comment: @TylerH Only edits made from the VLQRQ, not all edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to guess it was a mistake by the mod who processed the flag.  They probably didn't see the initial version of the answer.

Just as an FYI the timeline for this was:

- The [answer was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36261158/1) at `2016-03-28 11:12:25`
- The user deleted it at `2016-03-28 11:12:34`, then undeleted it a few seconds later at `2016-03-28 11:12:37`
- Your flag came in at `2016-03-28 11:13:03` just prior to their edit
- They then [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36261158/2) a few minutes later at `2016-03-28 11:17:03`
- A moderator reviewed and declined your flag about an hour later.

Typically, mods will mark these as helpful based on the initial version which is why I'm going to say this was a mistake.

Comment: Does that mean leaving a comment below the posts (for the mod to see the revision history) help?

Comment: @BhargavRao I would say no, that's just extra noise that isn't needed.  As I said, this was probably just a mistake.

Comment: @BhargavRao Mods can't see comments on flagged answers unless they click through, though, right?

Comment: @TylerH = that's right. To see everything we have to click through to view the post itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip bluefeet .... @TylerH Reading a few other meta posts, 'Yes', they can't see. But I am unsure of that. (or what ChrisF said ^ )

Comment: Yup, I didn't see the post had been edited; it happens. I think I reviewed this flag straight from the queue.

Comment: cue feature request asking for edit information to be included in moderator queue. :-)

Comment: Perhaps a flag should link to a particular revision, exactly as it was when flagged - rather than just to the post itself.

Comment: @Rob Eh, that wouldn't really help when an edit actually does fix a problem that was flagged (e.g. kinda what happened here), since a mod might be tempted to delete without realizing that the post is better now. An occasional flag getting declined instead of disputed doesn't seem like a big enough deal to make substantial changes here (although that's not to say that our mod tools are perfect by any stretch).

Comment: @AdamLear Yeah fair enough - perhaps a banner notifying the mod that the flag was for a previous revision (and a link to the revision)