# My flag was declined. Why?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903831/swiftui-datepicker-in-form-dismisses-when-keyboard-appears/68538825#68538825) as **not an answer**.

When I flagged, the answer was in [this state](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68538825/revisions).

[image]

The OP edited the answer later, but my flag was declined. Why?

Comment: This was my mistake sorry, I have no idea what I was thinking there while handling the flag. I always check if the post is edited via the flag dashboard, but looks like it has been missed. Also the user deleted the post and undeleted it, which should have cleared the flags but it wasn't? Did the new feature that unflags stuff after a owner deletes and undeletes remove the edited remark or was I just a moron? I'm confused about what happened there as well.

Comment: No need to sorry. We all are human and some time mistake happens. Thanks for honest reply.

Comment: *we all are human* .. checks SOBotics ....

Comment: Except community, even if it's not a robot.

Comment: @Shree I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Isn't [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317406/8967612) from the dup saying essentially the same thing that Bhargav said above?

Comment: Eh, I don't see any benefit in opening the question just for an answer that says "It was a mistake", maybe someone with a gold badge in discussion can just add https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319911/why-was-this-naa-flag-declined-on-a-random-text-post to the dupe list

Comment: I voted to re-open in case Bhargav Rao wanted to formally answer, but after re-thinking, what would be the point of that? If he wanted to answer, dude has, I believe, all the godly powers necessary.

Comment: @Shree The fact that the user deleted and undeleted the answer didn't impact the situation. However, the mod flag dashboard UI has changed a bit since the [original duplicate target answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317427/3773011) was written. There is an indicator in the dashboard when the post has been edited since the flag was raised, so it's not *necessary* to go searching for edits each time. Unfortunately, that indicator is small and the styling doesn't make it very noticeable, so it's easily missed.

Comment: Woo! The mod symbol just got BIG! And a LOT more obvious. It says Mod and everything!

Comment: @user4581301 no the diamond mod symbol got big. Use regular mods still don't have any :(

Comment: Then they need a symbol! Something people can stand behind and feel supported without being swaddled. Something strong. Bold, but not overwhelming. Something like the mighty walrus.